# Flutter overlay over other apps

Tags: flutter, overlay, flutter-showmodalbottomsheet

I want to build a Flutter App that can show information in a modalBottomSheet, but outside of the App.

The App should run in the background and when I want it to show something, it should show a modalBottomSheet over the curently used App. It doesn't matter if the user is in a App or just the Homescreen, important is that the App runs from the background and can overlay other Apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use [flutter_overlay_window](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_overlay_window). It can display your flutter app over other apps on the screen

Comment: I am also looking for something like this. But this lib only works with Android. Is there something that works with iOS and Android ?

Comment: currently, there is none that supports iOS